Blazor apexchart data not in correct categories
I'm having issues regarding the use of categories with apexchart. The data is always mapping to the wrong category.
I like to think I am missing something but I just can't seem to know what.
I'm trying to display data for one day, one column for each hour of the day.
I want the user to be able to see all the available labels so I have resorted to using categories, one category for each hour ("11:00").
So the list ends up beeing like this: ["00:00", "01:00", ...]
Then I format the Datetime property of the data to this format with just .ToString("HH:00").
Now, if I apply the the list of categories to the XAxis options like so:
private List<string >_categories = Enumerable.Range(0, 24).Select(i => _from.AddHours(i).ToString("HH:00")).ToList(); 

_options.Xaxis = new XAxis
{
    Title = new AxisTitle
    {
        Text = ClientTranslations.Time
    },
    OverwriteCategories = _categories
    Categories = _categories
};`

Then I get all the labels showing on the XAxis but the data goes into the wrong category.
It goes into the first category available and so on.. but is does not match to the correct category.
So if the list of data is [(1000, "09:00"), ...] then that first point will map to the first category "00:00" but not to the category "09:00"
I have tried having only Categories and/or only OverwriteCategories enabled but the data still goes into the wrong category.

I'm encountering the same issue. I think it's either a misbehavior in the library, or our use case is so odd and rare that it's not a thing.
I think the solution to this is to use the XAxisType="XAxisType.Datetime", like this:
<ApexChart TItem="BarGraphItem"
           Width="@("100%")"
           Options="BarGraphOptions"
           OnRendered="OnRendered"
           XAxisType="XAxisType.Datetime"
           @ref="@BarGraphRef">

If you use the .Datetime type, it's built in and does a lot of this for you. And it adds additional functionality such as zooming in or out.

Thanks for answering! When I tried to specifically set the XAxisType on the chart component itself the chart didn't display the XAxis categories as I wanted them to.
What I did in the end was to do some data processing after I fetched the data.
Essentially I grouped the fetched data into the hour value of their timestamps.
Then for each category I would insert that data or some values of it, f.e. summing up the weight or getting the count value, and insert that into a custom record. That list would eventually end up as the items in the chart component. So essentially each column in one item

I have found the solution...! You have to (1) make sure your data is sorted the by your x axis field, and (2) have data for every series, so if there's no record on a category add one with value 0 if missing. Looks like you figured out (2), I was messing up both (1) and (2) lol
